# Add categorical variable(gender) to Sparse Matrix for Multiclass Classification using sklearn

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am building a multiclass classification model using sklearn. I am converting my tweets into a 571x1815 sparse matrix of type with 34737 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format. I am trying to predict age groups based on history of tweets but I want to add an exogenous categorical variable (gender) to my sparse matrix and they use either Decision Tree or Random Forest to do my prediction. How do I add a vector to a sparse matrix?

```
def vectorize(df):
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=nltk.word_tokenize,token_pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,15}",stop_words="english",
                                  ngram_range=(1, 2),min_df=.01, max_df=.5,max_features=1815)#3000
bow_transformer.fit(df)
messages_bow = bow_transformer.transform(df)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)
messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
return messages_tfidf
```

[picture of the pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6IH5.jpg)

Comment: To add columns to an existing sparse-matrix: ```both = scipy.sparse.hstack((original_data, new_columns))```. Your code doesn't reflect at all, which data-types are used. It might be better to add the columns to your dataframe, before converting to a sparse-matrix. But like i said: it's unclear where you have sparse data-structures.

Comment: My sparse matrix is created after running my vectorize function on my collection of tweets. I then do use hstack to add the new column after binarizing my gender variable.